# Consuming json input from url ,deserialize into c# & retrieve values from web API

Tags: c#, json, web

I have been stuck in trying figure out the syntax for a particular scenario.

Scenario: When I give a JSON string as argument in the URL, I want the url to consume an API and retrieve the details from that API, as per the given input.

My project needs deserialization into c# so, I used JSON.NET for the same.
Say: input is - Profile-id : `123456789`
The output should consume details pertaining to that Pid and display.
The i/p given in url:
https://www.docscores.com/widget/api/org-profile/demo-health/npi/123456789

The expected o/p:
json string

What i have been doing is :

```
string url = "https://www.docscores.com/widget/api/org-profile/demo-health/npi/?profile-id=ShowProfile";
string data = GET(url);
dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

var phyRatings = Convert.ToString(jsonDe.profile.averageRating);
Console.WriteLine(phyRatings);

public string ShowProfile(string pid)
{
}

public static string GET(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

So, when I pass profile-id as `123456789` in the url, I want the syntax to extract other info with this Profile-id

I AM totally confused with the syntax in C#.  How can I pass the argument and write inside the ShowProfile function?  I searched everywhere but not able to find the correct syntax.

Can someone please tell me if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: A JSON string cannot be in an URL because it can contain invalid characters.  Usually when data is passed through a URL it's a query string or fragment string.  JSON is usually passed in the body of a HTTP request /response which usually means that the POST or PUT verbs are being used.  GET does not support the request having a body, only the response of a GET request can have one.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: .net framework 4.5 if thats not the correct syntax, can you please try helping me out in giving me the right one plz?

Comment: No, I mean what web framework are you using, if any such as ASP.NET MVC, WebForms, or otherwise, but upon futher review of your question it's irrelevent so don't worry abou tit.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Sounds like you have two questions here. First is how to pass your Profile-Id in the URL, and the second is how to deserialize the JSON result into a C# object. But let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

For passing `123456789` as your profile ID, you just need to concatenate it into the URL string. So you might have

```
public string ShowProfile(string pid)
{
    ProfileInfo info = GET(pid);

    // Do what you want with the info here.
}

public static ProfileInfo GET(int profileId)
{
    try
        // Note this ends in "=" now.
        string basePath = "/widget/api/org-profile/demo-health/npi/?profile-id=";
        string path = basePath + profileId.ToString();

        //...
```

`ProfileInfo` would be your custom class to match the JSON structure.

Then to deserialize the result, in your `GET()` method, you might instead try calling the service using `HttpClient` from the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package, and then read that directly into a C# object whose structure maps to the JSON response you get (see example below). Your `GET()` method could then return that object, and then it'd be trivial for the `ShowProfile()` method to read the properties you want from that C# object.

```
public static ProfileInfo GET(int profileId)
{
    try
    {
        // Note this ends in "=" now.
        string basePath = "/widget/api/org-profile/demo-health/npi/?profile-id=";
        string path = basePath + profileId.ToString();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.docscores.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ProfileInfo info = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProfileInfo>();
                return info;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

More code and info at [MSDN: Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: but this is for a particular product id = 1 and that is already hardcoded in the code. i am looking for a syntax where, a end user enters the id and the output is retrieved

Comment: @jn123 You can just have the value concatenated into the string from user input

Comment: oh.. can u plz give like an example? please